# RuntimeError: Can not put single artist in more than one figure when using matplotlib 1.5

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(1)                # the first figure
plt.subplot(211)             # the first subplot in the first figure
plt.plot([1, 2, 3])
plt.subplot(212)             # the second subplot in the first figure
plt.plot([4, 5, 6])

plt.figure(2)                # a second figure
plt.plot([4, 5, 6])          # creates a subplot(111) by default
plt.text(.5,1.5,'211',figure = 211) #tring to add text in previous subplot

plt.figure(1)                # figure 1 current; subplot(212) still current
plt.subplot(211)             # make subplot(211) in figure1 current
plt.title('Easy as 1, 2, 3') # subplot 211 title
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/ezhou/Desktop/python/test3.py", line 11, in <module>
plt.text(.5,1.5,'211',figure = 211)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 3567, in text
ret = gca().text(x, y, s, fontdict=fontdict, withdash=withdash, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 619, in text
self._add_text(t)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 1720, in _add_text
self._set_artist_props(txt)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 861, in _set_artist_props
a.set_figure(self.figure)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 640, in set_figure
raise RuntimeError("Can not put single artist in "
RuntimeError: Can not put single artist in more than one figure
```

I was trying to understand the kwargs 'figure' in class matplotlib.text.Text(), but it will always reply 'Can not put single artist in more than one figure'. So I was confused about how to use this 'figure' kwarg. Can anyone give me some advise? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not quite sure exactly what you are trying to test on this (to have '211' appear on fig.1 subplot?) but this throws no error for me with version 1.4.3. The only time I get any traceback is with `plt.show()` but it still plots the graphs (without the extra text). It's saying that the error is on like 11 but in your example `plt.text(.5,1.5,'211',figure = 211)` is line 10. Granted it's 1 line but is it just a blank line?

Comment: Thank you roganjosh, I am trying to understand what is the function of kwarg 'figure'. I found some people report this error when using matplotlib version 1.5+ and no error when using <1.5.

Comment: Actually, although I don't get an error, it doesn't work. `matplotlib.figure.Figure()` is different to `plt`, so you cannot pass that object under the `figure=` argument. I understand your question now and I'm curious too. I think you're misusing this parameter, but I can't work out actually why it's needed. Almost there... (I think :P)

Comment: Figure() is used for updating graphs i.e. something embedded in Tkinter. It allows you to set the parameters of a frame in an embedded graph and then update the data it shows. You have accepted the answer saying this cannot be done. Should I stop pursuing this?

Comment: Thank you! Please pursuing this, really appreciate.

Comment: I remember now that I did something similar with tkinter following the tutorials of "sentdex" on youtube. It is becoming clearer now why you need to use `matplotlib.figure` and not `matplotlib.plt` for such things. I'm just struggling to create a self-contained example for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shouldn't pass figure as a kwarg, instead use text method of a Figure (or Axes) instance. Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig1, fig2 = plt.figure(1), plt.figure(2)
sp1, sp2 = fig1.add_subplot(211), fig2.add_subplot(211)
sp1.plot([1, 2, 3])
sp2.plot([0, 1, 3])

fig1.text(.5, .3, 'whole figure')
sp2.text(.5, .5, 'subplot')
```

Please note that coordinates are relative (0, 1).

P.S if you find matplotlib needlessly complicated (as I do), you may wish to have a look at [Plotly](https://plot.ly/python/)

Comment: Thanks! I know this is the way will work, but actually I would like to know why I cannot pass figure as a kwarg? Since 'figure'  actually is a kwarg.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do it. All I know I couldn't get it to work. Documentation on the subject is pretty vague. I tried to look at the source code but still couldn't figure it out.

Comment: For future readers: matplotlib becomes much easier and friendlier to use if you use its [object-oriented API](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/lifecycle.html).